# Caching some tables of a Database in RAM

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql

I am building a database on SQL Server.

This DB is going to be really huge.
However, there are few tables which need to be queried very frequently and are quite small.
Is there a way to cache these tables in RAM for faster querying ?

Any ideas/links to make the database insertions/query faster will be highly appreciated.
Also, do I get any performance boost if I migrate from SQL Express to SQL Server Enterprise ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what `nature` of your application? web or winform?

Comment: I have a collection of files (over 1 million) which I am parsing and updating the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server will do an outstanding job of keeping small tables that are frequently accessed in RAM.

However, a small frequently accessed table does sound like a good candidate for caching at the application layer to avoid ever hitting the database.

If your database really is "huge", you will hit the 1GB RAM limit of SQL Express (and/or the 10GB per DB storage limitation) and will want an edition that does not have that constraint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: does SQL Server cache small tables on its own, or do I have to enable this option through some configuration ?   
I believe the data will be stored in the disk, so why do you think I will hit the 4GB RAM limitation ?

Comment: SQL Server will use *all* of the RAM you give it, on it's own (up to the RAM limitation of the SQL Server edition you are using).  It's very good at sorting out what needs to be in RAM.  No need to tell it what to place in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data from the table and store into the DataTable Variable。
You Should create suitable index and you and make the query faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the C# then you may have try data caching. 
You just need to follow 3 steps:

- Fetch your result to a list
- Now cache the list of data
- Whenever you need to query cache result, cast your cache object to concern list type.

Following is the example code:

```
List<type> result = (Linq-query).ToList();
Cache["resultSet"] = optresult;
List<type> cachedList = (List<type>)Cache["resultSet"];
```

Now you may perform Linq query over cachedList which actually uses cached object.

**Note:** For caching any object you may use more precise approach like following, this provides better control over caching.

```
Cache cacheObjectName = new Cache();
cacheObjectName.Insert("Key", value, Dependency, DateTime, TimeSpan, CacheItemPriority, CacheItemRemovedCallback)
```

Answer (score 0):

More a page is used by queries more are chances that the page will be in memory.But it will be at page level rather than table level. Everytime it will be referenced its count will be increased and a background process (lazy writer) usualy decrease the count for all the pages. When a new page is required to bring to  memory ;sql server will write the page with least count to disk.Thus if your table's pages are accessed frequently there are high chances that the count will be high and thus those will stay in memory for longer.But if you will have some kind of a big query which reads lots of data from different tables which say is more than your memory then even those pages might be thrown out of the cache.But if you do not have those kind of queries then the chances are high that pages will stay in the memory.

Also, it means the same page is accessed a number of times.If diff processes will read diff pages from same table then you might not have very high use count for all of your pages and thus some of them could be written to disk.

Read below blog for more details on how buffers etc works.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/elisabeth_redei/archive/2009/03/01/bufferpool-performance-counters.aspx

Comment: this `hit` will depend on the row size also. Think of the scenario when the size of a row equals 1 page ?

Comment: do you have row size of 8k in your tables?I have mentioned this in my answer "If diff processes will read diff pages from same table then you might not have very high use count for all of your pages and thus some of them could be written to disk." This indirectly means the almost similar.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often these small tables are changed, [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) might be a good option. Essentially, you subscribe your application to changes in a data set in the db. A canonical example is a list of vendors. Doesn't change much over time but you want the application to know when it does change.

Comment: what if my application is the one changing data in these tables. Earlier I was querying the table for duplicates before adding every entry. If the entry did not already exists, I added the new one.
Then I made a column `UNIQUE` and avoid this query and the addition of the new entry is simply discarded by the Database. However, almost 8 out of 10 entries turn out to be duplicates, so I am unnecessarily submitting the jobs to the DB which I want to avoid.

Comment: It depends on how concurrent things need to be. Is your application the *only* thing updating the data? If so, is database access serial (i.e. not parallel)? If you can be assured that your cached version is in sync with the database and you can query your cache. But I have to wonder: are you actually seeing a problem with the current behavior? I ask because many applications have this usage pattern and consider it the cost of business. So unless you've measured this as your bottleneck, I wouldn't worry about it.